# React Recoil Outside of React Component - Observable / Subscriptions

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I've been using Recoil and [recoil-nexus](https://github.com/luisanton-io/recoil-nexus) to use atoms outside of a React component. Specifically in classes (not react classes).

While Nexus works fine, I haven't been able to find a solution to subscribe to a atom and run a callback when the value changes.

There is already a question on their Github with exactly the same use case however there hasn't been an answer yet. The only difference is that I don't care about the old value, although that would be nice to have. https://github.com/luisanton-io/recoil-nexus/issues/26

Is this currently possible with Recoil?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion: use Atom Effects

I don't think `recoil-nexus` has a role in subscribing to atom changes as this is already something you can handle applying [effects](https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/atom-effects) on atoms.

Specifically in order to run an effect when you are setting new values (effectively "subscribing" to atom changes) you could do something like:

```
export const appLoadingAtom = atom({
    key: "app-loading",
    default: false,
    effects: [
        ({ onSet }) => {
            onSet((newValue, oldValue) => {
               // Do something here with atom values...
               console.table({ newValue, oldValue }); 
            });
        }
    ]
});
```

**Notice:** such `onSet` logic will **always run on any atom update**, no matter whether the new values are set via Nexus or via standard Recoil hooks.

##### Side note: subscribing to `setRecoil` in `recoil-nexus`

If you were instead looking to run an effect *only if* Nexus itself is performing an atom update, then this is not currently supported, since I could not see any practical use for that insofar. I would encourage and appreciate you to [open another issue](https://github.com/luisanton-io/recoil-nexus/issues) for that specifically so that it could be picked up.